# Chrome - stuck in WAITING_FOR_AVAILABLE_SOCKET

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The webpage of my webserver recently started getting stuck on WAITING_FOR_AVAILABLE_SOCKET after a while. It is random in behavior, some times the issue occurs in 15 minutes and some times after more than an hour.

[image]

The network-export logs show that requests are waiting for socket. My understanding is that chrome allows 6 sockets per domain at a time and there is a timeout associated with the socket. Also, if the tab is closed, the sockets should get closed automatically as the request are cancelled by chrome.

The logs show 6 Active sockets even when all (my) website tabs are closed.

[image]

But the problem persists even after closing all the tabs and just using the API from the address bar (new tab). And the issue doesn't go away even after hours unless sockets are flushed/chrome is restarted.

Is chrome (recently updated) leaking the sockets or could this be a backend issue?